# universal precision control in Mathematica

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

There are many ways to control precision in Mathematica, such as PrecisionGoal in specific build-in commmands or SetPrecision to some variables. I got two questions below,
(1) If I do not set any options for precision, in what precision will Mathematica calculates the numberical expression ? Single float or double float ? Or something else ?
(2) How can I set the precision globally ? Not only in the build-in functions, but all other expressions I write by my self.
A certain question might be more clear. In my program, I have to use the funtion `Dot` and `MatrixExp` or functions defined by myself. How can I control the precision both in the output and calculation process ?
It seems that such questions are easy to solve in Fortran or C......

Comment: If you don't specify precision at all, most functions will operate at either the precision of the input, or `WorkingPrecision` (whichever is less). Look up `$MinPrecision` and `$MaxPrecision` (which can be equal to each other). The lowest allowable precision is none and the maximum is infinity. And, remember that *Mathematica* can use adaptive precision for functions such as `N` or that have a `PrecisionGoal` option.

Comment: `MachinePrecision` is the closest to a C floating point number.  The name suggests it depends on your machine, but for most that means a 64-bit float, often called "double precision."  There's only one flavor of machine precision.  Then there's [`ArbitraryPrecisionCalculations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionCalculations.html) which you can read about.  There is nothing like it in basic C; it would have to be implemented through a library.

Comment: Arbitrary precision is implemented using GMP, FWIW.